# Pug call js function from another file inside template

Tags: javascript, templates, pug

I can't solve this for almost four hours, and i can't find any helpful documentation for this kind of problems. This is the issue, I'm using pug/jade templates and i want to call function inside pug template to transform some data
This is the main template:

```
 /** main template */
section
  each pet in pets
    .pet
      .photo-column
        img(src= pet.photo)
      .info-column  
        h2= pet.name 
        span.species= (pet.species)
        p Age: #{calculateAge(pet.birthYear)} //here I need to call calculateAge function
        if pet.favFoods
          h4.headline-bar Favorite Foods
          ul.favorite-foods
            each favFood in pet.favFoods
              li!= favFood
/** end main template **/
```

This is the external function:

```
/** calculateAge.js **/

 module.exports = function(birthYear) {
   var age = new Date().getFullYear() - birthYear;

   if (age > 0) {
     return age + " years old";
   } else {
     return "Less than a year old";
   }
 };
/** end calculateAge.js **/
```

What shell I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 11):

There may be better way to handle this, but I usually do it by importing the external module and then passing it as part of template context object. That means the code that renders the template should be something like:

```
const calculateAge = require("calculateAge"); // change path accordingly

router.get("/main", function(){
  let pageInfo = {};
  pageInfo.title = "Demo";
  pageInfo.calculateAge = calculateAge;
  res.render("main", pageInfo);
});
```

Now, you can access `calculateAge` in your template. If this module is used a lot in most of the templates, then you should pass it as part of `res.locals` or `app.locals` so that it is available for all templates without the need to append it for every path request.

Answer (score 4):

In PUG options use `locals` property to import functions you want to use inside your templates.

```
const calculateAge = require('./calculate-age');

const config = {
  pug: {
    locals: {
      calculateAge,
    },
  },
};
```

Then you can use it in all your templates like this (please note the extra unescaping tag `!{}`):

```
p Age: !{calculateAge(pet.birthYear)}
```

Comment: I use Expressjs. Where exactly should I put the configuration code?

Comment: @user8555937 Does this help you? `app.locals.foo = 'foo';` https://pugjs.org/api/express.html

Comment: Where do you put the configuration code?

Comment: Downvoting as this doesn't explain where to pass the `config` object

Comment: What the heck is "PUG options" ?

Comment: It depends how you use PUG. In my case, I used PUG via Gulp. If you use Express then `locals` does not refer to PUG options but Express options. See http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals However, the PUG itself have options as well https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#options It really depends in what stack you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your function available in pug like this:

```
//assuming you're using express
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.locals.someFunction = input => input * 5;
// or
import {someOtherFunction} from "packageOrFile";
app.locals.someOtherFunction = someOtherFunction;
```

In your pug you then can do

```
span= someFunction(10)
span= someOtherFunction(123)
```

This is basically what mahish wrote in his comment, but it actually answers the question satisfactory and [here's the documentation](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#:%7E:text=Properties-,app.locals,-The%20app.locals).

Answer (score 0):

Like in raw HTML if you want JS to execute in a sepcific part you need a script tag to enclose the js you want to use.

```
 span.species= (pet.species)
 p Age:
     .script 
         calculateAge(pet.birthYear) 
 if pet.favFoods
```

Answer (score -2):

You can write javascript with **.script** tag

```
 script.
   $( document ).ready(function() {
   calculateAge(params)
 })
```